# Stylize text in td elements

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a failty big table to do.
I always found difficult in stylizing them so I can assume mine is a basic question.
I have some TDs with fairly long text in it. Currently the table style is set with "white-space: nowrap".

What I want to achieve is to split these td text into a fixed number of "lines" (let's say 3) so the row may be taller mut the single cell is somewhat smaller.

white space normal:

```
--------
- text -
- text -
- text -
- text -
- text -
--------
```

white-space: nowrap

```
---------------------------------
- text text text text text text -
---------------------------------
```

I want:

```
-------------
- text text -
- text text -
- text      -
-------------
```

Comment: Set a width to the `td`....

Comment: thank you for your input. This set the height of the td to a certain amount, yet the text develops horizontally

Comment: Set a **width** on the `td` is what is suggested...

Comment: ah ok sorry. Thank you. This set the width attribute with the correct amount "es: width: 300px", yet if nowrap the text develops fully horizontally, if wrap it's the same.

Comment: If you want text to wrap, you have to remove the `nowrap` property completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a width on your columns to determine how much text to fit in there. I have created a JS Fiddle with 3 examples of how this works:

https://jsfiddle.net/2rhzymwc/

```
<table class="wrap-width">
<tr>
<td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
<td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
<td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
</tr>
</table>

.wrap-width td {
  width: 100px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

With respect to your comment, do you mean longer as in specifying the height to be slightly longer than the content? Or that the width/height of one cell should be longer than the others? It is quite unclear what you are asking for, check out these further examples:

https://jsfiddle.net/jz8gn8ax/

Comment: Yeah, i know what do you mean, yet if you for example set   .wrap-width td {
  width: 500px;
}  
  
it's exactly as wrap, I'd like to have tds a little "longer"                                                                                          https://jsfiddle.net/jz8gn8ax/

Comment: I want to split the content so the TD develops horizontally, but not like the wrap options wich basically adapts to the longer words. If I operate on the width attribute, it works in a sense that if I set a smaller width in a table with wrap the column shrinks to the desired width. My case: basically I have this long table wich is inside a wrapper with overflow-x: auto so you can slide, two or more of the colums may contain a longer text (not a lot), i'd like the column to be a little taller so the text doesn't have to develop fully horizontally, or vertically like in wrap.

Comment: Im really sorry but even with all of this description I still have no idea what you are trying to achieve, maybe add further illustration, screenshots and examples to the question and I will take a look.

Comment: dont' worry  atm I am using max-width and text-overflow: ellipsis in tds, and the handle the rest with javascript, thanks anyway. i will accept your answer